# Windows Terminal not changing directory via script

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I have file assist.cmd, which is within my %path% with the contents

```
pushd m:\Documents\Code\assist
```

When I type assist on windows terminal (the new one) I get:

```
PS C:\Users\User> assist

C:\Users\User>pushd m:\Documents\Code\assist
PS C:\Users\User>
```

When I copy the pushd command myself, it works but not when used from the script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this tagged `PowerShell`? Something to do with _the script_ you are not showing?

Comment: I'm using powershell from the new windows terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a BAT script "assist.cmd" a new child process "cmd.exe" is started. The command processor executes the BAT script and the current working directory of that process is actually changed. Thereafter the process is terminated after the BAT script completed.

The current working directory of a child process does not change the working directory of the PowerShell process. That's why a .cmd script is not usable to perform the intended assistance.

You can use a PowerShell script "assist.ps1" that contains the `Push-Location` or its alias `pushd` and call it with the [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) syntax

```
. assist.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, when running a .cmd file, you're running the pushd that comes with cmd, not the pushd powershell command.  https://blog.brainasoft.com/all-internal-commands-of-cmd/